# Can't access my Lenovo bios after installing Ubuntu as a dual boot with windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, lenovo

I'm new to Linux and I was trying to set up dual boot on my Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E430 by installing Ubuntu. I already have Windows 10.

For the installation I prepared a bootable DVD with Ubuntu MATE but it didn't boot at first. Then, I entered into the BIOS via windows 10 mode and I set up my boot on legacy mode (my mistake here). After doing that, the DVD was available in the startup menu and I was able to install Ubuntu.

After I installed ubuntu I was not able to get back to Windows 10 because my laptop is still in legacy mode. But the real problem here is that I can't repair this situation because I'm not able to get back to BIOS. I tried several times all the methods on Lenovo to interrupt the startup and enter the BIOS and change my boot mode back to UEFI but nothing worked.

How can I get into it?

Comment: Usually ESC immediately after pressing power works. Or this: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-E-and-Edge/ThinkPad-Edge-Unable-to-enter-the-BIOS-with-F1-Key-with-Windows/ta-p/927937 and, needless to say. it has nothing to do Ubuntu.

Comment: Also this: https://support.lenovo.com/ar/en/solutions/ht500222

Comment: you can try: press "c" in grub to get command line. and see if `fwsetup` will do it.  once in the setup options, you want UEFI on and secure boot off in order to install ubuntu.

Comment: As a final resort, unplugging the hard disk will usually force the computer into its firmware setup utility. This may cause UEFI boot entries to be lost, though, which could complicate booting after you re-attach the drive, so you should definitely hold this as a last resort option. Also, some modern computers make it difficult to unplug the hard disk, especially if you're not comfortable opening up computers and mucking with their innards.